# Effects of using a different PWM frequency than specified on device

Tags: pwm, control, fan

I am wiring up a fan speed control circuit that creates a PWM frequency that is used by a PWM fan (the fan and its specs are pictured below). The fan claims that its PWM control is done through a 25kHz frequency. What will happen, in any situation in general, if I don't match 25kHz exactly?

[image: San Ace 40 fan with a 25kHz PWM frequency]

Comment: Contact the manufacturer for certainty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will use 20kHz or 30kHz, odds are everything is fine. Other than that, you have to provide more details. I would bet you can go down to 10kHz with no problem.